# Why this answer got so many down votes

Tags: discussion, down-votes

[This is a very good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540526/better-net-sdk-support-canon-or-nikon) but I wonder why [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14099383/1248266) got so many down votes, is it because he doesn't have enough reputation ?

Comment: I assume it is because it is pretty much a link only answer and it doesnt really answer the question.

Comment: The answer is currently on -4. That might happen if 2 people downvoted it and flagged it as spam as that flag gives an additional -1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect the down-votes come from the fact that:

1. It's little more than a link only answer
2. The link is to the answerers own blog.
3. It doesn't really answer the question.

There are rules against self promotion in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) and link only answers aren't good answers as if and when the linked page goes dark the "answer" becomes useless.

The posters reputation is only relevant in that it shows that they are a new user who doesn't know the rules. A comment as to why the answer is a bad answer would have been nice, but there are no requirements on people to back up down-votes with comments.

Comment: Why does this have upvotes then ? Its barely an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5875084/1488917

Comment: @AshRj "answered May 3 '11 at 20:08" might well have something to do it. Compared to "answered 6 hours ago" from the answer being discussed.

Comment: Yes, probably that.

Comment: Right, coming in 2 years late and promote his own stuff in his very first post. Not a good start!

Comment: A nice case of (shameless) self promotion, which is now deleted.